# Howto create a real 3d game, stereo. (not 3d graphics, but 3d screen)

Tags: 3d, stereo-3d

I need your help. Is it possible to write a game in 3d on a canvas? If so, how. Maybe a small example of 2 blocks?

** With 3d I don't mean 3d graphics in OpenGL, or on canvas while you use your brain to apply vector calculus to project the 3d graphics on a 2d screen. I mean program for LG Op3d/HTC Evo 3d!

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking.  Can one write 3D games for 3D output devices?  ... Well, if the answer were "no" then nobody would buy such output devices.

Answer (score 1):

There is a link to download HTC stereoscopic API at:
http://htcdev.com/devcenter/opensense-sdk

Answer (score 1):

For the HTC Evo 3D go to HTC developer website **htcdev.com** There you can download the OpenSense SDK which contains the S3D API and sample code for S3D rendering (Stereoscopic 3D rendering).
You have to render the scene twice which gives you more control on the S3D effect on the one hand, but on the other hand you have to choose your camera view's carefully.
(With other hardware accessories, like nVIDIA's 3d vision, a 3D scene is rendered twice by the driver, no options to change the views of the two cameras from the programmer's point of view).

Answer (score 0):

Nvidia seems to have a driver or library that automatically converts a conventional 3D game to the 3D stereo game. http://www.nvidia.com/object/product-geforce-3d-vision-wired-glasses-us.html

I guess if you want to do it yourself, you just need to render the same scene twice with slightly shifted camera. and somehow you combine the two rendered result together, you will make your game real 3D.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: [link](http://blog.us.playstation.com/2010/12/20/stereoscopic-3d-on-the-ps3-full-list-of-all-3d-games-and-blu-rays/).

More elaborate answer:

Many 3D TVs have accept multiple types of input to render 3D, most notably - side by side.

If you are interested in getting a quick start at producing a 3D game (or just a 3D scene), you could use a graphics engine (such as [jMonkeyEngine](http://jmonkeyengine.com/)), create 2 view ports side by side, and render your scene in each of the view ports from separate camera angles. If you connect your 3D TV and set its 3D mode to side by side - you will see the scene in 3D.

Answer (score 0):

HTC has an sdk for the use in thair HTC EVO 3d MPhone.